# Taking some array without looping

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm still newbie in Perl. I'm trying to take some arrays and put them in another array without using loop.

```
my @array1 = ("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr");
my @array2=$array1[2 .. 4];
```

but it can't work.

I want the result of @array2 is "def ghi jkl".

Comment: Note that Perl uses zero based indexing, so you're actually after indices `1`, `2` and `3`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `@` for array slice instead of scalar marker (`$`):

```
my @array1 = ("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr"); 
my @array2=@array1[2 .. 4];              # ====> @array1 not $array1
print join(",", @array2), "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for a list slice is `@array[EXPR]` (not `$array[EXPR]`), so you want

```
my @array2 = @array1[2..4];
```

Note that the above has three loops. If you wanted to avoid looping, you'd have to use

```
my @array2;
$array2[0] = $array1[2];
$array2[1] = $array1[3];
$array2[2] = $array1[4];
```

I doubt you actually wanted to avoid looping despite the request, though.

Comment: Or `my @array2 = ($array1[2], $array1[3], $array1[4]);` if he wants a more compact expression, but I agree that it's probably not what he actually wants.

Comment: @flesk, Nope, the still leaves the loop in the aassign. ("For each scalar on the stack, remove it from the stack and append it to the array.") The other two are in the range and the slice respectively. ("For each number in the range, create a scalar on the stack." and "For each scalar on the stack, remove it and place the corresponding array element on the stack.")

Answer (score 1):

change your statement to below:

```
@array2=@array1[2..4];
```